# Create and use an instance of an class who's class name is only known at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a list of class names and methods that can only be read during runtime.  Is it possible to create a class dynamically like that?  I'm currently using C# 4.0.

Comment: No offence, but I think you are asking the wrong question.  Can you add some detail as to what you are trying to accomplish?   As to actually answer your question... can you create a class at runtime using C#, yes, you can actually embed the C# compiler inside your code, so you can do a ton of things like this.  Can you bind to a foreign object ( aka, a C method inside a DLL ) by name at runtime, no, at least, not without some serious magic.  I have a feeling though, when you explain WHY you are trying to do it, your question will change completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little unclear whether you want to *define* a type at runtime and *define* methods against it, or whether you want to create an *instance* of an already-written type, and *call* methods on it.

Fortunately both are possible.

The second scenario is more likely, so you'd want to look at reflection (below) - but note that there are performance penalties associate with this (and small things like "what arguments does the method take" become very important).

For the first scenario, you'd need to look at `TypeBuilder`, but that is **much** more complex. Another option would be `CSharpCodeProvider` and dynamic assembly loading, but again - not trivial by any stretch.

```
using System;
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class Foo {
        public void Bar() {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo.Bar called");
        }
    }
}
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        string className = "MyNamespace.Foo, MyAssemblyName",
            methodName = "Bar";
        Type type = Type.GetType(className);
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        type.GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(obj, null);
    }
}
```

---

To include parameters (comments) you pass an `object[]` instead of the `null`:

```
using System;
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class Foo {
        public void Bar(string value) {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo.Bar called: " + value);
        }
    }
}
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        string className = "MyNamespace.Foo, MyAssemblyName",
            methodName = "Bar";
        Type type = Type.GetType(className);
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        object[] args = { "hello, world" };
        type.GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(obj, args);
    }
}
```

If you are doing this *lots* (for the same method) there is a way to improve performance via a typed delegate, but this doesn't gain you much for *occasional* calls.

Comment: Thank you for the response, very helpful.  I was wondering if it's possible for Bar() to have a parameter like Bar(string input) and how that would be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IL emit functionality straight out of the .Net framework to accomplish this.  You will need to learn IL in order to dynamically generate type information at runtime--this is not for the feint of heart.

[Introduction to Creating Dynamic Types with System.Reflection.Emit](https://web.archive.org/web/20100418004903/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/johnsPerfBlog/articles/49829.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As I can't really answer that you are asking I will answer a number of question you might want to ask.

#### Can I create an instance of class and call its method where both class and method are specified at run time?

Sure. The simple way first. Use a `if` statements:

```
var className = "MyClass";
var methodName = "MyMethod";


if (className == typeof(MyClass).Name) {
  var instance = new MyClass();
  if (methodName == "MyMethod")
    instance.MyMethod();
  if (methodName == "MyOtherMethod")
    instance.MyOtherMethod();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance of a class for you.

```
var className = "MyClass";
var methodName = "MyMethod";

//Get a reference to the Assembly that has the desired class. Assume that all classes that we dynamically invoke are in the same assembly as MyClass.

var assembly = typeof(MyClass).Assembly;
//Find the type that we want to create
var type = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Name == className);
if(type != null) {
  //Create an instance of this type.
  var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  //Find the method and call it.
  instance.GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(instance);
}
```

#### Can I generate a class at run time?

Yes you can but it's hard. If you are an experienced C# programmer, know a bit of C++ and assembly, you should be able to grock it. If not, don't bother.

Microsoft provides a library to emit Intermediate Language code called, surpose, [`IL.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator%28VS.95%29.aspx). There are very few problems that warrant using this method, amongst those are mock object generation and some aspects of Dependency Injection. It is quite likely that your problem is better solved in another fashion.